# what is the importance of Benzophenone in distillation

Tags: organic-chemistry

when we realize a distillation of solvent we use benzophenone ,

what is the importance of this latter , Is is considered as an initiator of this operation, that's true ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Your question is rather unclear and as such may well be closed. Please [edit] it to include more detail as to what you actually mean. (I have a suspicion which would make a good question but I don’t know if it’s true.) Learn more about editing and how the site works in the [help].

Comment: The importance of benzophenone in organic reactions

Comment: Sodium is insoluble in most solvents. When it reacts with benzophenone, it produces dianion that is moderately soluble and is a strong reducer, cleaning the solvent of anything reducible.

Answer (score 3):

Ethereal solvents are often distilled from metals such as sodium In the presence of benzophenone as an indicator.

When the still is good, the benzophenone is blue/purple, when it goes yellow/brown the still is bad.

Classically we thought that the colour was related to moisture (ie. A purple colour indicated dryness) however its now generally agreed that the colour is to do with the absence of oxygen rather than moisture.

The distillation can be done without this indicator, indeed short path distillation almost never uses indicators. The benzoophenone is just useful in recycling stills as it allows one to see when th still needs attention.